# How to map a SQL Perspective project to use CoreData

Tags: sql, core-data

I an new to core-data but I do have some experience in SQL in general. I have been researching my issue for a while and I can not seem to find the exact situation I want.

I am building an app for my Son's daycare to help them track kids signing-in/out etc, in nutshell without going over details I want to persist data.

I dealt with DBs before and I am very comfortable with SQL so SQLlite learning curve will not be a problem, but everyone tells me to use core data.

The way I see my data/schema is really simple 1 table :) so what I was planning to do in SQLlite is very simple 2 Tables for storage with Basic FK and 2 objective-c classes to map my model (First object will have standard type members and an array of the second object), and 1 Factory Class that wraps my SQL lines to INSERT, SELECT , DELETE , UPDATE!!

I really want to use CoreData to experiment with it, but every example i saw online deals with model object that just saves that object to the store, I need to tread my data as rows of each object.

I really appreciate any help or guidance on where to look for a good jump point.

Comment: With Core Data, each entity type is comparable to a SQL table, and each instance is comparable to a table row. I'm not sure I understand the conceptual difficulty you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

You can tread your data row by row, each row as a NSManagedObject using a NSPredicate on a NSFetchRequest sent to NSManagedObjectContext fetch: method.

The question is why you want/need to tread your data one row at a time. Much of the strength of Core Data is in mapping of UI elements such as tables, fields etc to entities, attributes and relationships in the model. A data model is created in XCode Model Editor and the mapping is done in the XCode Interface Builder. So that you don't need to fetch data row-wise and write all that code. Core Data does it for you.

If you want to use insert, delete, update etc. in your application then you may want to look at https://github.com/mhakman/osx-cocoa-odbc where you find Objective-C framework for ODBC databases.

/Mikael